# How to replace special character in Linux VI Editor?

Tags: linux, vi

I want to remove some special characters from a file in linux using vi editor, such as

```
{ 
}
:
[
]
```

I tried below pattern but not working for all possible symbols above.

`:%s/\{//g`

got an error :
E866: (NFA regexp) Misplaced {
E64: { follows nothing
E476: Invalid command

Comment: Can see it's working with below method : 

``` :%s#{##g ```

so I am just replacing a '{' with a blank space.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, see `:h :s` and `:h pattern`. See `man 7 regex`.

`\{` starts a *bound* in basic regular expression. vi does not really use basic regular expression, but anyway, it's like close to it. You want to match character `{`, and not repeat previous pattern, so just match `{`.

```
:%s/{//g
```

> for all possible symbols above.

If you want to put `[` `]` inside a *bracket expression* `[...]` you have to put them as the last/first. So like `[]]` matches a single `]`, like `[][]` matches `[` or `]`.

```
:%s/[]{}:[]//g
```